# Не строится до конца таблица python

Tags: python, циклы, таблицы

Должна построиться примерно такая таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается только так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что может быть не так?
Код программы:

```
import math as mt
x = 1
xf = 2
dx = 0.1
print('%10s' % 'x', '%10s' % 'y(x)')
print('-'*10, '-'*10)
N = int((xf-x)/dx+1)
for i in range(N):
    if x < 1.3:
        y = mt.pi * x ** 2 - 7 / x
    elif x == 1.3:
        y = 1.5 * x ** 3 + 7 * mt.sqrt(x)
    else:
        y = mt.log10(x + 7 * mt.sqrt(x))
print('%10.2f' % x, '%10.4f' % y)
x += dx
```

Answer (score 1):

Соблюдайте табуляцию

```
import math as mt
x = 1
xf = 2
dx = 0.1
print('%10s' % 'x', '%10s' % 'y(x)')
print('-'*10, '-'*10)
N = int((xf-x)/dx+1)
for i in range(N):
    if x < 1.3:
        y = mt.pi * x ** 2 - 7 / x
    elif x == 1.3:
        y = 1.5 * x ** 3 + 7 * mt.sqrt(x)
    else:
        y = mt.log10(x + 7 * mt.sqrt(x))
    print('%10.2f' % x, '%10.4f' % y)
    x += dx
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Anton, спасибо здесь выражается принятием ответа (клик на галочку возле него).